# Xcode UI Testing: staticText's label not updating as text is updated?

Tags: ios, automation, xcode-ui-testing

**Background**

I am investigating migration of our Appium-based automation to Xcode UI Testing. Given that our app is written in Objective C I need to use Objective-C for the test code as well.

The app I am automating tests for, has a progress bar whose values I want to read. It's not a [UIAProgressIndicator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAProgressIndicatorClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009911), just a `UIAStaticText` whose value increases from "0" to "100%".

The `XCUIElement` corresponding to this staticText can be accessed as

```
[[app staticTexts] elementBoundByIndex:1]
```

The progress bar will take different amounts of time - and I need to monitor the progress, which will involve reading the value (and parsing it of course).

I tried getting the value using various methods - `[XCUIElement value]` and `[XCUIElement label]`.

```
NSString *prog = [[[app staticTexts] elementBoundByIndex:1] label];
```

The `label` approach is getting me the progress string, so I am doing this in a loop, for e.g.

```
  int i=0;
  while (i<5) {
     //custom sleep method
     [self.helper threadSleepForSeconds:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
     //now get progress text
     NSString *prog = [[[app staticTexts] elementBoundByIndex:1] label];

     i++;
    }
```

However, as the progress changes, the `label` attribute does not update - it seems to keep showing the *first value that was read*, as though it was cached somewhere.

i.e the log output shows (assuming the first value read was 19%):

```
19%
19%
19%
19%
```

I am quite unable to figure out why this happens. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

There is no synthesized event, so Xcode doesn't attempt to take a new snapshot of the UI elements on the screen.  This is by design so that assigning multiple ui element variables in a specific view doesn't overwork your computer.

Unfortunately, manual testing may be your only option if you're not satisfied with unit testing.